# How can I create a qqplot based on equal values in one column in a loop?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I would like to create a code for several stacked qqplots using the following data.frame. Each plot should refer to a specific net number and should look more or less like this:

[image]

(The original data.frame contains 20 volume classes (VCL) for every Net number, here displayed are only the values for Net 1).

It should be possible to apply the code to other data.frames with a different amount of nets.

```
   > f.perr.p
    VCl simtype Net         perr
1    V1       F   1 2.413043e-03
3    V1       F   3 1.000000e-03
5    V1       F   5 2.173913e-04
14   V2       F   1 2.673913e-03
16   V2       F   3 1.130435e-03
18   V2       F   5 3.043478e-04
...
261  V1      nF   1 4.195652e-03
263  V1      nF   3 4.152174e-03
265  V1      nF   5 3.760870e-03
274  V2      nF   1 4.260870e-03
276  V2      nF   3 4.304348e-03
278  V2      nF   5 4.021739e-03
...
```

So, my approach would be to create a for-loop, telling R to create a plot with the data that is equal in column "Nets", then doing the same for the next net number until I have a stacked plot of, in this particular case 3 plots referring to Net 1, Net 2 and Net 3.
I started with this, but I have no clue how to proceed:

```
x<-which(f.perr.p$VCl == "V1" & f.perr.p$simtype == "F") # to identify how many plots should be created

> x
[1] 1 2 3 

# VCl = x-axis,
# simtype = colorfill, 
# Net= plot.nr, 
# perr=y-axis

op<-par(mfrow=c(length(x),1))
for(i in 1:length(x){
ggplot(f.perr.p, aes(factor(VCl), perr, fill = simtype)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", colour="black")
})
par(op)
```

I know that this code can't work at all, but I cannot figure out how to make clear that with each run of the loop only the rows with a specific net number should be considered.
What do I have to include and where?

I hope I expressed my problem in a clear way. Your help is very much appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: Just use `facet_wrap(~ Net)`.

Comment: thanks a lot! That was exactly the hint I needed!